# Add generic project to specific project with git

Tags: git, gitlab

For example, I have generic git project called `project_A` which contains scripts and other files that I like to provide in specific git projects called `project_B`, etc.

```
(generic)      project_A
               ^        ^
              /          \
             /            \
(specific)  project_B     project_C ...
```

How can I setup the git specific projects `project_B` ... to get the latest changes of my scripts and files from git generic project `project_A`?

Comment: This is call dependency management. Use a dependency manager for it. Not git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [submodules](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

From the docs:

> It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use another project from within it. Perhaps it’s a library that a third party developed or that you’re developing separately and using in multiple parent projects. A common issue arises in these scenarios: you want to be able to treat the two projects as separate yet still be able to use one from within the other.
>
> Git addresses this issue using submodules. Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits separate.

So in your case you'd need to add `project_A` as a submodule to your other projects e.g.:

```sh
$ cd project_B
$ git submodule add <link_to_project_A>
```

Edit: formatting